# Hack an existing Wordpress template to display content from specific page

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that has its own set of templates and I want to hack one of those templates to display the contents of a specific page (ID 129).

I've tried several different solutions I've found on the internet from "The Loop" to a double loop to trying just the simple line `<?php get_post( $id=129, $output=OBJECT, $filter=display ); ?>`.  At best the original plug-in page shows with no modification, at worst I break it and get a blank page.

Comment: Please, add your solution as an auto-response so you can mark it as a selected answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Only the page content is showing and not the title, and I need to pick through the plugin's CSS to style it, but it's showing!!!  I did this:

```
<?php $examplePost = get_post(129);

echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $examplePost->post_content ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$that_page = get_post(129);` the variable `$that_page` will hold all the data associated with the entity 129.

You can do:

```
$that_page = get_post(129);
echo '<pre>';
die(var_dump($that_page));
```

And it will print everything that is available. To access a property of `$that_page` use the `->` notation. You are probably looking for:

```
$that_page->post_title;
$that_page->post_content;
```

And as you've figured it out already, the best way to print them is with:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $that_page->post_content);
echo apply_filters('the_title', $that_page->post_title);
```

The `apply_filters` function transforms the provided string (content or title) to ensure it's safe and that it will be displayed correctly. `the_content` filter for instance transforms new lines (breaks made using your enter key) into paragraphs (`<p>text</p>`) or breaks (`<br>`).

For other types of data the above filters are inappropriate. You can simply do a `echo $that_page->some_property;` but be aware that it might be required to do some kind of sanitation depending on the type of value the property holds.